Global error handler for ASP.NET Core application
I am trying to configure a global error handler for my web app.
Configuration
In the Startup.cs Configure method:
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();
}

Middleware
public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
{
    // RequestDelegate denotes a HTTP Request completion.
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            var response = context.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
            // Creates an ErrorReponse Model out of the error message using the Fail method
            var responseModel = ErrorResponse<string>.Fail(error.Message);
            switch (error)
            {
                case ExceptionService e:
                    // custom application error
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    break;
                case KeyNotFoundException e:
                    // not found error
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    break;
                default:
                    // unhandled error
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    break;
            }
            var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(responseModel);

            // Create a new ITempDataDictionary object
            var tempData = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITempDataProvider>().LoadTempData(context);

            // Add key-value pairs to the temp data dictionary
            //tempData["ErrorMessage"] = "An unexpected error occurred."; 
            
            tempData["Error_Message"] = error.Message.ToString();
            tempData["Error_StackTrace"] = error.StackTrace.ToString();
            tempData["Error_Source"] = error.Source.ToString();
            tempData["Error_TargetSite"] = error.TargetSite.ToString();

            if (error.InnerException != null)
                tempData["Error_InnerException"] = error.InnerException.ToString();

            // Save the temp data dictionary to the HttpContext
            context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITempDataProvider>().SaveTempData(context, tempData);
            //context.Response.Redirect(result);
            context.Response.Redirect($"/Error?code={response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }

}

Error Controller
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IEmailService _emailService;
    private readonly AppConfiguration _appConfig;
    private readonly AppMailSettings _mailSettings;

    public ErrorController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
                            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
                            IEmailService emailService,
                            IOptions<AppConfiguration> appConfig,
                            IOptions<AppMailSettings> mailSettings)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _emailService = emailService;
        _appConfig = appConfig.Value;
        _mailSettings = mailSettings.Value;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Error")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Error(string code)
    {
        var Error_Message = TempData["Error_Message"];
        var Error_StackTrace = TempData["Error_StackTrace"];
        var Error_Source = TempData["Error_Source"] ;
        var Error_TargetSite = TempData["Error_TargetSite"];

        ErrorViewModel model = new ErrorViewModel();

        model.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, an application error occured. Our support team has been notified.";

        model.ErrorDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        model.StackTrace = Error_StackTrace.ToString();
        model.InnerException = TempData["Error_Message"].ToString();
        model.Source = Error_Source.ToString();
        model.TargetSite = Error_TargetSite.ToString();

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        var baseUrl = "http://localhost:44350";

        if (user != null)
        {
            model.UserId = user.Id;
            model.UserName = user.UserName;
            model.Role = user.UserType;
            
            var mailRequest = new MailRequest();
            //mailRequest.ToAddresses = new List<string> { "email@email.net", _mailSettings.ErrorEmailAddress };
            mailRequest.ToAddresses = new List<string> { "email@email.com", _mailSettings.ErrorEmailAddress };
            mailRequest.Subject = "WFC Plus Error Report";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine($"User: {model.UserName}");
            // other details in string builder
            sb.AppendLine($"Is Development: {model.IsDevelopment}");
            mailRequest.Body = sb.ToString();
            await _emailService.SendEmail(mailRequest);

        }
        return View(model);
    }
}

Problem
Invoke method of ErrorHandlerMiddleware is getting hit on startup so I know that the environment setting is correct, but exceptions that I am triggering in testing are not getting handled by the middleware.
I am not sure how to proceed.

What exceptions are you triggering and where?

Inspect environment variables set in testing environment. They maybe have values different from what you expect.

Could you please help check whether this document helped your not? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@Peppermintology My code works well when I throw an exception, but isn't the intent of "global" error handling to catch unhandled exceptions?
